# How to create an image from a canvas and a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, capture

I have a canvas, and a textarea that resides on top of the canvas:

```
<canvas id="ideaBox" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<textarea id="ideaTextArea" rows="15"></textarea>
```

I want to capture the contents of the box, including the textarea, into an image. Is that possible?

I tried using:

```
var MIME_TYPE = "image/png";
var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL(MIME_TYPE);
```

but it omits the text, because the text is in the textarea, not in the canvas.

I also tried using html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but you can only pass one element into the script, so I can't pass both the canvas and the textarea.

Anyone have ideas, or experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to append a caption to the bottom of an existing canvas:**

Create a copy of the canvas with the textarea text appended to the copy.

[image]

1. Calculate the height of the wrapped text from the textarea assuming that text must be wrapped within the width of the original canvas (see the example code below).
2. Create a new in-memory canvas.
3. Size the new canvas to the original canvas width but to the original canvas height plus the wrapped text height.

   ```
   newCanvas.width=originalCanvas.width;
   newCanvas.height=originalCanvas.height+wrappedTextHeight;
   ```
4. `DrawImage` the original canvas contents to the new canvas.
5. Draw the wrapped text at the bottom of the new canvas.
6. Create a new image from the new canvas using `.toDataURL`.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var text='Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.'
var fontsize=14;
var fontface='verdana';

// testing: draw something on the canvas
ctx.fillStyle='gold';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(75,270);
ctx.lineTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(125,270);
ctx.lineTo(150,50);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(250,160,150,270);
ctx.lineWidth=15;
ctx.strokeStyle='purple';
ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineJoin='round';
ctx.stroke();

// append a caption at the bottom of the canvas
applyCaption(canvas,text,fontsize,fontface);


function applyCaption(origCanvas,text,fontsize,fontface){
  // calc the height of the wrapped text
  var height=wrapText(0,0,text,fontsize,fontface,canvas.width-20);
  // Create a new canvas
  // Resize the new canvas same as original canvas
  //   but taller by the text height
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
  c.width=origCanvas.width;
  c.height=origCanvas.height+height;
  // draw the original canvas contents to the new canvas
  cctx.drawImage(origCanvas,0,0);
  // draw the wrapped text at the bottom of the new canvas
  cctx.fillStyle='white';
  cctx.fillRect(0,c.height-height,c.width,height);
  cctx.fillStyle='black';
  wrapText(10,c.height-height,text,fontsize,fontface,canvas.width-20,cctx);
  // create an image from the new canvas
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
  img.src=c.toDataURL();
}

function wrapText(x,y,text,fontsize,fontface,maxwidth,context){
  if(!context){
    // we're just calculating the wrapped text height
    // so create a throw-away context to work with
    var context=document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  }
  var startingY=y;
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';
  var space='';
  var lineHeight = fontsize*1.286;
  context.font = fontsize + "px " + fontface;
  context.textAlign='left';
  context.textBaseline='top'
  for (var n=0; n<words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + space + words[n];
    space=' ';
    if (context.measureText(testLine).width > maxwidth) {
      context.fillText(line,x,y);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
      space='';
    } else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.fillText(line, x,y);
  return(y+lineHeight-startingY);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
img{border:1px solid lightgray; }
```

```html
<h4>Original canvas & New canvas with appended caption</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=250 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized after I posted that I could just append the text, and make the textarea hidden.